# Login or Sign up program python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have a program that lets a user create an account if they don't have one, but if they do it lets them sign in and checks the username and password with the ones they put in when they made an account. 
This code works for the sign up, but not for the login part  / checking if person has already made account.

```
import os.path
if os.path.exists("username"):
    login()
    else:
        make_account()

def make_account

filename = ("username");
with open (filename, "w") as f:
  f.write (input("Enter a username: "));

filename = ("password");
with open (filename, "w") as f:
  f.write (input("Enter a password: "));


def login
username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")
check()

def check
if username == open("username").read(): and
passsword == open("password").read():
    print("Successful login")
else:
    print('Incorrect')
```

Comment: And ? Have you errors ? Please edit your question if something is wrong with the code.

Comment: Are you aware of the syntax for defining a function?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How to have a program that goes to the login if text found in the files (the username and password) instead of making new 'accounts' every time the program is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import os.path
if os.path.exists("username"):
    login()
else:
    make_account()

def make_account():

    filename = ("username");
    with open (filename, "w") as f:
      f.write (input("Enter a username: "));

    filename = ("password");
    with open (filename, "w") as f:
      f.write (input("Enter a password: "));


def login():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    check()

def check():
    if username == open("username").read() and passsword == open("password").read():
        print("Successful login")
    else:
        print('Incorrect')
```

Comment: works for sign up, but when ran again comes up with: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 27, in <module>
    login()
  line 16, in login
    check()
  line 19, in check
    if username == open("username").read() and passsword == open("password").read():
NameError: name 'username' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os.path


def login():
    def make_account():

        filename = "username"
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(input("Enter a username: "))

        filename = "password"
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(input("Enter a password: "))

    def login():
        def check():
            if username == open("username").read() and\
                    password == open("password").read():
                print("Successful login")
            else:
                print('Incorrect')

        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        check()

    if os.path.exists("username"):
        login()
    else:
        make_account()
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Instead, include explanations of the changes you made, and tell us _why_ you think this answers the question and how it works. See [answer] for more information on writing good answers.